# Is it possible to style differently links with same classes but different title tags?

Tags: html, css, hover, anchor

Still working on my website without access to the HTML.

I'd like to know if it is possible to create different hover states of image links where parent divs have the same name but different title tags.

Code:

```css
.project-panel .pp-thumb img {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 170px;
  height: 127px;
}

.project-panel .pp-thumb:hover img {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-Girls-thumb.gif) no-repeat;
  width: 170px;
  /* Width of new image */
  height: 127px;
  /* Height of new image */
  padding-left: 170px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
  <a href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone-duplicate-3" title="Danger Zone"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-Girls-thumb.png" width="200" height="150"></a>
  <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone-duplicate-3" title="Danger Zone">Danger Zone</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
</div>

<div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
  <a href="http://couill.art/project/danger-ii" title="Danger II"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/chauve-souris-0-00-02-19.png" width="200" height="150"></a>
  <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="http://couill.art/project/danger-ii" title="Danger II">Danger II</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
</div>
```

I managed to change the hover state for all links with CSS above, but I guess creating a different state for each link is another story.

Thanks for your guidance :)

Comment: [`.pp-thumb[title=…]{}`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: In addition to AjAX his comment: [W3schools documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thank you @AjAX but could tell me how I add the hover state ? `.pp-thumb[title=…]:hover{}` or something else ?

Comment: Does it — not — work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector.

```css
.project-panel .pp-thumb img {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 170px;
  height: 127px;
}

.project-panel .pp-thumb:hover img {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-Girls-thumb.gif) no-repeat;
  width: 170px;
  /* Width of new image */
  height: 127px;
  /* Height of new image */
  padding-left: 170px;
  background-size: contain;
}

a[title="Danger Zone"]:hover>img {
  background: red;
}

a[title="Danger II"]:hover>img {
  background: #00ff11;
}
```

```html
<div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
  <a href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone-duplicate-3" title="Danger Zone"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-Girls-thumb.png" width="200" height="150"></a>
  <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone-duplicate-3" title="Danger Zone">Danger Zone</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
</div>

<div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
  <a href="http://couill.art/project/danger-ii" title="Danger II"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/chauve-souris-0-00-02-19.png" width="200" height="150"></a>
  <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="http://couill.art/project/danger-ii" title="Danger II">Danger II</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not categorize your `img` tags with ids and use those ids in css.

```
<img id="category1" src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-Girls-thumb.png" width="200" height="150"></a>


<img id="category2" src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/chauve-souris-0-00-02-19.png" width="200" height="150"></a>
```

Now use these IDs in css:

```
.project-panel .pp-thumb #category1{

}
.project-panel .pp-thumb #category2{

}
```

Comment: Yeah I'd like to do that but I can't edit the HTML as it's from a WordPress theme.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following `CSS`

```
.pp-thumb a[title="Danger Zone"]:hover{
  color: red;
}
.pp-thumb a[title="Danger II"]:hover{
  color: yellow;
}
```

You can also check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qh8fmj1k/